# Getting MenuItem Class Missing Error on YouTube Chromeless Player API

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube

Consistently getting this error all of a sudden:

VerifyError: Error #1014: Class com.google.youtube.ui::MenuItem could not be found.

Anyone else seeing this?  Any suggestions on how to get around?  I've added error handling throughout the code, but error is still being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I started receiving this same error today when using the AS3 Player API.

From what I can tell,

hxxp://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/apiplayer3-vflHUesdc.swf

loads up

hxxp://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/ad3-vfl33FPYU.swf,

within which `com.google.youtube.modules.ModuleBase` tries to import `com.google.youtube.ui.MenuItem`, but it's nowhere to be found.

ad3-vfl33FPYU.swf was last modified this morning at 4:01 CDT.

See also: http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/youtube/Nm_K9hW7GQ4/discussion

Comment: Works now with the new apiplayer3-vflyx11oN.swf.